# PHP - DOMXPATH how to return ONLY direct descendants

Tags: php, xpath, xsd, domxpath

I am trying to use DOMXPath to get a list of child elements in an XSD file that are direct descendants of an element called 'Item'. However using the 2 xpath options listed below, it always includes grandchildren in the results aswell as child nodes

cheers

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('xsdfile.xsd');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//$xpath_str = '//xs:element[@name="Item"]/descendant::xs:element';
$xpath_str = '//xs:element[@name="Item"]//xs:element';

$results = $xpath->evaluate($xpath_str);
```

Comment: how about `//xs:element[@name="Item"]/xs:element`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Under `element` there is `complexType`, then `sequence`, `choice` or `all`, and then the actual child elements, so the XPath should be:

```
//xs:element[@name="Item"]/xs:complexType/*/xs:element
```

(`*` = any element) or

```
//xs:element[@name="Item"]/*/*/xs:element
```